# How To Redirect .htaccess domain, http to https. cant find what works for me in any thread

Tags: php, apache, ssl

I finished setting up a script on a domain with ssl on it but i ca't get it to redirect

I already tried using the redirect option in my cpanel, i noticed some codes were added to the .htaccess file but when i try to run the site, it actually redirects but instead of loading, it says too many redirects

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTPS:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dayret\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dayret\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/dayret\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

After running the above code i get the site redirecting to https but stops and brings up `"This page isn’t working dayret.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"`

Comment: This is what I use, straight out of my `htaccess` file.   I won't post it as an answer, because I am **also** redirecting `www` to `non-www`  --  
`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]` 
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]`
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]`
`RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]